# document.getElementsByTagName("*"); returns more than one tag

Tags: javascript, html

```
var allthosetags = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
```

returns more than one html tag per index

```
allthosetags[0].innerHTML
```

gives me a meta head link and script not just meta.

Is this standard behavior?  W3c says I am supposed to get a collection of nodes.

Comment: A collection could mean that the collection has nested nodes. This is why each index has more than one index (nested arrays of html elements, for example)

Comment: Just press F12 on this page and type the `document.getElementsByTagName("*")` into the console. You'll get a visual of all the elements it's got and how heavily nested it gets

Answer (score 1):

since * matches all the tags ,you should change your code to:

```
var allthosetags = document.querySelectorAll("meta")
```

this may solve your problem!

Answer (score 0):

It not only gets the tag, but the contents of the tags, because the contents are part of that individual tag. This IS standard behavior. 
You could perhaps try document.getElementsByClassName(), and give every tag the same class, but I suspect that would have a similar result

Answer (score 0):

Just press F12 on this page and type the document.getElementsByTagName("*") into the console. You'll get a visual of all the elements it's got and how heavily nested it gets

[image]

You can see that each of the collection items has additional elements inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't. You could either do two queries using `getElementsByTagName` or use `querySelectorAll`. As:

```
var tags = document.querySelectorAll('input,a,p')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aLnqh88y/